# Instagram api know if current user has liked the media in media api?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, https, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using following api to fetch all posts of an user.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#reading

for fields I'm using
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media#fields

response
[image]

I how can I know if the current authenticated user has liked the media of the above listing.

Any boolean value to get?

Comment: No, that is not available. The overall like count is all you can get.

Comment: Ok @CBroe. How can i show if user has liked the media or not. Any workarounds?

Comment: Doesn't look like you can.